# speed up a matrix rowMeans operation

Tags: r, rcpp

Consider the following matrix,

```
nc <- 5000
nr <- 1024
m <- matrix(rnorm(nc*nr), ncol=nc)
```

I wish to take the difference between the `rowMeans` of two groups of identical size taken at random in this matrix.

```
n <- 1000 # group size

system.time(replicate(100, {
   ind1 <- sample(seq.int(nc), n) 
   ind2 <- sample(seq.int(nc), n)
   rowMeans(m[, ind1]) - rowMeans(m[, ind2])
}))
```

It is quite slow, unfortunately I didn't understand the output of Rprof (it seemed most of the time was spent on `is.data.frame`??)

Suggestions for something more efficient?

I have contemplated the following:

- `Rcpp`: from my online readings I believe R's rowMeans is quite efficient, so it's not clear it would help at this step. I'd like to be convinced of where the bottleneck really is first, maybe my whole design is suboptimal. If most of the time is spent in making copies for each of the smaller matrices, would Rcpp perform better?
- updating to R-devel, there seems to be a new `.rowMeans` function more efficient yet. Has anyone tried it?

Thanks.

Comment: If you do the sampling, subsetting and differences all in Armadillo, I would suspect you gain a little.  Should be quick enough to try via RcppArmadillo, no?

Comment: It would be fairly easy, yes, but hopefully I can get away with pure R. Essentially, I'll try when/if all R approaches fail. Also, I have no experience with managing random numbers in Rcpp.

Comment: Rcpp sugar gives you the same stream(s) R uses :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each `rowSums()` call on a subset of columns from `m` can be seen as the matrix multiplication between `m` and a vector of `0` or `1` indicating the selected columns. If you juxtapose all those vectors, you end up with a multiplication between two matrices (which is much more efficient):

```
ind1 <- replicate(100, seq.int(nc) %in% sample(seq.int(nc), n)) 
ind2 <- replicate(100, seq.int(nc) %in% sample(seq.int(nc), n))
output <- m %*% (ind1 - ind2)
```

Comment: that sounds very promising, thanks! I'll need to convince myself that it's doing the right thing, but it's certainly fast and elegant.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need 2 calls to `rowMeans`.  You can do the subtraction first and call `rowMeans` on the result.

```
x1 <- rowMeans(m[,ind1])-rowMeans(m[,ind2])
x2 <- rowMeans(m[,ind1]-m[,ind2])
all.equal(x1,x2)
# [1] TRUE
```

`is.data.frame` is part of the checks done in `rowMeans`.

UPDATE: regarding `.rowMeans` in R-devel, it looks like it's just a straight call to the internal code (assuming `do_colsum` hasn't changed).  It's defined as:

```
.rowMeans <- function(X, m, n, na.rm = FALSE)
    .Internal(rowMeans(X, m, n, na.rm))
```

In your case, `m=1024` and `n=1000`.

Comment: In fact, this is even better than you say because the OP has 200 calls (2 * 100 replicates) to `rowMeans` which can be reduced to 1 ... `rm <- rowMeans(m); system.time(replicate(100, { rm[sample(seq.int(nc),n)]-rm[sample(seq.int(nc),n)]}))` takes 0.1 elapsed seconds ...

Comment: @Joshua, are you sure that taking the diff of the two matrices won't be just as expensive as computing the rowMeans of one of them? It's the same number of operations after all.

Comment: @BenBolker. It was also my initial guess that the `rowMeans(m)` could be stored outside the `replicate` call but it is not solving the same problem. The OP's output is 1024-by-10; what you and I both thought about would be 1000-by-10...

Comment: @flodel: my thought was it would save an extra function call and avoid the `is.data.frame` calls, but the timings don't seem to bear that out...

Comment: @BenBolker I don't see how this would work. I want to compute `rowMeans` for submatrices selected from columns of the original matrix. If I take `rowMeans(m)` all the columns have collapsed into 1, effectively.